# Azure KeyVault access from Azure DevOps release pipeline with no secrets list permissions

Tags: azure-devops, azure-keyvault

TL&DR - My DevOps release pipeline keeps failing with 'does not have secrets list permission on key vault

I am stumped with this one, and asking for help, please.

### The Error

`2023-06-07T07:12:53.7594988Z ##[error]Get secrets failed. Error: The user, group or application 'appid=***;oid=b5a[REDACTED];iss=https://sts.windows.net/292[REDACTED]/' does not have secrets list permission on key vault 'kv-d-chatgeni;location=australiasoutheast'. For help resolving this issue, please see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2125287. The specified Azure service connection needs to have Get, List secret management permissions on the selected key vault. To set these permissions, download the ProvisionKeyVaultPermissions.ps1 script from build/release logs and execute it, or set them from the Azure portal..`

### Data

The service principle for devops is

| Object | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Application (client) ID | 14e[REDACTED] |
| Object ID | a7e[REDACTED] |
| Application (client) ID | 292[REDACTED] |

I noticed that the Object ID in KeyVault is b5a[REDACTED], but same Application (client) ID

I ran the following command on the Object ID reported

`az role assignment create --role "Key Vault Secrets User" --assignee  b5a[REDACTED] --scope /subscriptions/ade[REDACTED]`

I even tried with the Application ID of the Service Principle as I noticed that Access Policies use the Application ID

```
az role assignment create --role "Key Vault Secrets User" --assignee  14e[REDACTED] --scope /subscriptions/143[REDACTED]
```

My Tenant ID: `292\[REDACTED\]`

### TASK

```
steps:
- task: AzureKeyVault@2
  displayName: 'Azure Key Vault: kv-d-[REDACTED]'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'app-[REDACTED]'
    KeyVaultName: 'kv-d-[REDACTED]'
    RunAsPreJob: true
```

### Other

1. I have given Contributor Role on subscription to b5a[REDACTED]
2. My KeyVault is set to use RBAC
3. I created another test KeyVault with Access Policies, and gave object List, Get permissions.  It worked fine in the build pipeline, unfortunatly our production environment uses RBAC.

I am stumped.  I have read tons of posts, many are Access Policy driven.  The RBAC ones are vague and ambiguous.

I am stumped.  I have read tons of posts, many are Access Policy driven.  The RBAC ones are vague and ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

When I used **Vault-access policy** as Access configuration without assigning policy to service principal, I got **same error** while running same DevOps task as you:

```
steps:
- task: AzureKeyVault@2
  displayName: 'Azure Key Vault: [REDACTED]'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '[REDACTED]'
    KeyVaultName: '[REDACTED]'
    RunAsPreJob: true
```

**Response:**

[image]

If you are using **RBAC** as Access configuration, you need to assign proper role to Azure DevOps service principal.

> To assign role to service principal, you need to pass **`objectID`**
> of it in CLI command.

You can find **`objectID`** of that service principal in **Enterprise Applications** of your tenant by searching with it's name like below:

[image]

I have key vault named **`srikv07`** with Access configuration set to RBAC like below:

[image]

Now, I ran following CLI command by including **`objectID`** of service principal and assigned **Key Vault Secrets User** role to it successfully like this:

```
az role assignment create --role "Key Vault Secrets User" --assignee 6431c433-d0a2-4662-a267-xxxxxxxx  --scope /subscriptions/b83c1ed3-c5b6-44fb-b5ba-xxxxxxxx
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I ran same **DevOps task** as you with that service principal, I got the results successfully like below:

```
steps:
- task: AzureKeyVault@2
  displayName: 'Azure Key Vault: [REDACTED]'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '[REDACTED]'
    KeyVaultName: '[REDACTED]'
    RunAsPreJob: true
```

**Response:**

[image]

In your case, make sure to pass **`objectID`** of service principal that can be found in **Enterprise applications** of your tenant.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply @Sridevi, much appreciated.  I will try this out over the weekend.