# Unable to get password from Azure keyvault for azure sql server admin password using terraform azure pipe line , its working in local

Tags: terraform, azure-keyvault, azure-service-principal, serviceconnection

Error: making Read request on Azure KeyVault Secret sqladminpassword: keyvault.BaseClient#GetSecret: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 --
Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="Forbidden" Message="The user, group or application
'appid=***;

does not have secrets get permission on key vault

Note: I am getting this error while deploying through azure pipeline, working while trying from local.
Using terraform for this

I have tried the all the permission , everything is fine , how to fix it

Comment: Could you check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76421094/azure-keyvault-access-from-azure-devops-release-pipeline-with-no-secrets-list-pe/76423234#76423234?

Comment: Your `terraform apply` deployment action worked locally, probably because you were authenticating against your `user principal` when running `az login` command before the `terraform` commands. Assuming you were using ARM service connection in your pipeline task, which was authenticating against `service principal`. According to the error message, this underlying service principal (App registration) was not granted surfficient permission to retrieve secret from keyvault.

Comment: Yes you are right , but i checked all the permission level , its good

Comment: You can set the environment variables `ARM_CLIENT_ID` `ARM_CLIENT_SECRET` `ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID` and `ARM_TENANT_ID` with their corresponding values on your local machine first and then test the terraform actions authenticating against the same service principal. Remember to `az logout` from your signed-in user principal.

Comment: By the way, you can also share a minimal .tf template to reproduce the issue in the post with screenshots of your service connection information, service principal client information and permissions of the underlying service principal to related resources. Don't forget to scrub the sensitive information.

Answer (score 0):

#### Point Number 1

Please check if the service principal associated with your service connection has access to get secrets from your Azure key vault.
If not you need to grant the Key Vault Administrator role to the service principal associated with your Azure pipelines.
[image]

#### Point 2

Check granted permit in terraform configuration to azure pipeline service principal

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "example" {
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
  tenant_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

  key_permissions = [
    "Get",
  ]

  secret_permissions = [
    "Get",
  ]
}

data "azuread_service_principal" "example" {
  display_name = "example-app"
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "example-principal" {
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
  tenant_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id    = data.azuread_service_principal.example.object_id

  key_permissions = [
    "Get", "List", "Encrypt", "Decrypt"
  ]
}
```

Comment: its setup already the same ,getting the same error,but its working through local and i have permission of Owner. From local its picking the password from the keyvault and assign to the sql admin password, , from pipeline cant able the get the password but the service connection is owner access